# Magento worldship Business rules need some Information. How I can get information from Magento?

Tags: magento2, ups

I need some information from magento
`1.Magento Address
2.Magento API endpoint(ex. /index.php/api/v2soap/index)
3.Port
4.Magento Api Username
5.Magento Api Password`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**.Magento Address:** Your domain URL means `http://www.example.com`

.Magento API endpoint(ex. /index.php/api/v2soap/index m) /soap/?wsdl&services=integrationAdminTokenServiceV1

See at
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/soap/bk-soap.html
http://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-api/

**3.Port:** 80 if it  http ,https 443.

**4.Magento Api Username:** you need to create from admin panel, admin panel.Check the blog http://blog.i13websolution.com/magento-2-create-soaprest-api-user/
**5.Magento Api Password**